# how to run a python file within python script?

Tags: python-3.x, os.system

This is a python script where I want to run start.py but it is not running. Can anyone help?

```
import numpy as np
import os

os.system("source ~/.bash_profile; python3 $XSPEGLIB/start.py")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: You can import the other python file then call the function directly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-do-i-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: usually the os.system command does the job (just tried it now on a personal script), can you show us the .bash profile and your python code in start.py ?

Comment: @CollinMatz , I tried  but since it has source bash_profile. It is not working in a usual way.

Comment: @mrCopiCat , these two are different command. so if you want to run it in a terminal you simply give first source ~/.bash_profile , enter and then $XSPEGLIB/start.py. But I made this new script file where I want to run start.py by using os.system.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question, I know that these are two different commands, and i know what os.system does, im asking you to show us your code to fetch where the problem is :)

Comment: @mrCopiCat okay. that problem has been solved . os.system("bash xspeg") working fine but now I have one more problem that, when I directly run python3 start.py from the terminal, I see the output but with script that I don't see it.